# Typo3: External URL should open with target=_blank

Tags: hyperlink, external, typo3, new-window

I have created a page with the type `external URL`. In the tab "General" I can specify the protocol and the URL. In another tab I can specify the URL alias and the target. But the target is already _blank. In the frontend the link still opens in the same window. I'm using Typo 4.5.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. In a TYPO3 v4.5.6 installation the link opens in a new window as expected. Are you talking about a link via the navigation or via a content element?

Comment: I found the error: I used a link to an external link. I only tried to add the `_blank` on the external link, not the link before. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Yes, if you use a shortcut to a link you should set the shortcut to open to "_blank".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `link` which pointed to an `external URL`. I only tried to set the `_blank` at the `external URL`. Now with setting it at both it works.